# Datagridview Persian Formatting

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to print a string in a cell of my datagridview which includes both Persian and English characters or even from any language. When I print this value in the specified cell it became somehow badly formatted.

Here is the picture:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: you would want to look at Culture or UTF-8 Encoding or both..

Comment: Could you please give me a link or sth?? I have already set this onLoad of my form:
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fa"));

Comment: here is a DataGridView Printer Class example from CodeProject that you may what to check out as well http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13678/The-DataGridViewPrinter-Class

Comment: Printing From DataGridView http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16670/DataGridView-Printing-by-Selecting-Columns-and-Row | http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25638/Printing-a-DataGridView-on-DotNet-Framework

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming Persian is read right-to-left? We're having a lot of the same issues in our Hebrew translations!

You'll want to look at setting the `RightToLeft` property to `Yes` on any controls that will use both languages.

Comment: Yes I know RTL is the answer, but I couldn't find any option for making a column of a datagrid RTL, but there is this option for make the whole datagridview RTL...

Comment: That's not possible. `RightToLeft` only applies to controls, you'll have to set it for the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

All the strings stored in string are in fact Unicode.Unicode. Read: [Strings in .Net and C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/strings.html) and [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Edit: I suppose that you want the Convert function to automatically change \x11 to \u25c0, but the problem here is that \x11 is valid in almost any encoding, the differences usually start in character \x80, so the Convert function will maintain it even if you do that:

```
string reEncodedString = null;
byte[] unicodeBytes = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value);
byte[] sourceBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode,
                                sourceEncoding, unicodeBytes);
```

You can see in [unicode.org](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/PC/CP850.TXT) the mappings from CP850 to Unicode. So, for this conversion to happen you will have to change these characters manually.

you want to also make sure that if you are going to use Farsi Characters make this line of code

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo language = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fa-ir"); 
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(language);
```

and to set the Characters back to English use this bit of code

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo language = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us"); 
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(language);
```

Comment: I have used the Answer that you said, but I still got the same result:
string reEncodedString = null;
                            byte[] unicodeBytes = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(result);
                            byte[] sourceBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode,
                                                            Encoding.UTF8, unicodeBytes);
                            //Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1200);//unicode encoding

                            message.Operator = read = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sourceBytes, 0, sourceBytes.Length);