# .NET can't read arabic character from oracle with charset "WE8ISO8859P1"

Tags: c#, .net, oracle10g

I have developed a web based application using C# with ASP.NET that reads from oracle database..
I've deployed it before and it was working perfectly.. but this time I'm deploying it with an oracle database that its character set is " WE8ISO8859P1 " .. and there are some data in Arabic stored in the database..

The problem is:
The .NET reads Arabic characters corrupted (some thing like this : " ÇáÝÑÚ ÇáÑÆíÓí "), but when using SQL PLUS it reads Arabic normally;

I've searched and found this [OTN: Database Character set](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=504267)

Any solution to make it read data correctly?

Comment: look at the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278600/datagridview-persian-formatting#comment11697656_9278600  also GOOGLE this System.Globalization.CultureInfo and do a GOOGLE Search for UTF-8 Encoding using C# and Oracle

Comment: Well thanks, but no solution yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your database is configured incorrectly.

The [ISO-8859-1 character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) does not support Arabic data (I'm assuming that since you only mentioned the database character set that you're storing the data in `CHAR` or `VARCHAR2` columns rather than `NCHAR` or `NVARCHAR2`).  You cannot properly store Arabic data in `CHAR` or `VARCHAR2` columns in a database where the database character set is `WE8ISO8859P1`.  You would need to [change the database character set](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch11charsetmig.htm#g1011430) to something that supports Arabic data in order to properly store Arabic data in `CHAR` or `VARCHAR2` columns.  Alternately, if your national character set supports Arabic, you could store the data in `NCHAR` or zNVARCHAR2` columns but that may entail application changes to support these data types.

Comment: In the database the columns data type is NVARCHAR ..
and yes .. the database isn't configured correctly but it's not my database so I can't change it.. my bad luck :(

Comment: @Ibn-Tashfin - Then your application cannot work correctly.  Just like your application probably wouldn't work if someone decided to install it in an Oracle 7 database, your application has a dependency that the database is able to properly store Arabic data in `CHAR` and `VARCHAR2` columns.  You can either configure the database to allow that or you can modify your application to support  `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR2` data types.

Comment: @Justin.. What do you mean by this : "You can either configure the database to allow that" I didn't got it?

Do you mean a modification to the database is possible to solve the problem ?

Comment: @Ibn-Tashfin - Yes, you can change the character set of an existing database.  In my answer, I linked to the 10.2 Globalization Support Guide's chapter on how to change the character set of an existing database.

Comment: @Justin.. I woulda vote your answer up but I need 15 points :) .. thanks .. I will read the link you provided and post back here.

Comment: Although I didn't solve the problem yet, but changing character set is my answer, thanks. But I don't understand yet how can it save data in Arabic using the ISO-8859-1 character set although it is not supporting Arabic?

Comment: @Ibn-Tashfin - It can't save Arabic data correctly.  When an application sends a character to a database, it's really sending a binary stream.  That binary stream can be interpreted as many different characters depending on the character set.  If you send a hex 0xE5 over the wire, for example, that would be a 'å' character in the ISO-8859-1 character set and a `ن` in the ISO-8859-6 character set (which does support Arabic).  If the two sides aren't interpreting the binary stream as using the same character set (or both sides don't support a character), you get garbage.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `Unicode=true` in the connection string? See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d7h4ycx(v=vs.80).aspx

If that doesn't work, try reading it as binary using `OracleDataReader.GetBytes`, then encoding using codepage 1256 (Arabic). Something like:

```
var buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead = oracleReader.GetBytes(columnIndex, 0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
String value = new String(new System.Text.Encoding(1256).GetChars(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
```

Comment: Reading data in binary and then interpreting it as coming from a different character set may appear to work but it's a very poor architectural approach.  You would make the data unreadable to any application other than yours.  You would make it very likely that some routine database maintenance in the future will cause major headaches-- if someone exports the data and imports it into another database, your application may not be able to read it any longer.